# Makefile if statement does not include source file

Tags: c, makefile, contiki

I have written this part of a Contiki Makefile:

```
fake_eh = 1
CFLAGS += -DSIMULATED_EH=$(fake_eh)

ifeq "fake_eh" "1"
CONTIKI_TARGET_SOURCEFILES += energy-harv.c
endif
```

However, even if the condition fake_eh equal to 1 is true, the file energy-harv.c is not linked.

If I comment the ifeq - endif lines, the compilation works. Where is the if statement wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
ifeq "fake_eh" "1"
```

you may try:

```
ifeq ($(fake_eh),1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well,

```
ifeq "fake_eh" "1"
```

asks whether both *strings* are the same. Do you see why they are not?

If not: one of them should be a variable. :-)